# how to render the plural of "looks like one"

Tags: word-usage

> He saw the creatures in the distance were actually dogs or at least looked like **ones/some/such**.

Normally I find this kind of sentence with a singular object, ergo my question. Are the three words in bold all correct in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is forcing the sentence into a direction that a native speaker is not likely to take.

> He saw (that) the creatures in the distance were actually dogs, or at
>   least ...

is likely to be completed in any of these ways:

> (they) looked like dogs
>
> (they) seemed to be (dogs)
>
> it looked that way

The plural pronoun you want would be an unnatural choice:

at least looked like __________  [something other than "dogs" repeated]

None of your suggested pronouns is idiomatic there.  You might say

... looked *to be* **such**.

but that phrase is not likely to come from the lips of any contemporary  speaker of mainstream American English, though you might hear it in a regional dialect, or find it used in a tale about pirates with eyepatches.